# Open folder in PowerShell without using Shift key

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, powershell

I know that I can open a folder in a new PowerShell window from the windows explorer context menu by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while right clicking. Is there any tweak to get this command shown in the context menu without the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why using Shift is problematic - that will allow people to suggest alternative solutions that will actually work for you, not just whatever comes on their mind.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it's not really problematic - I just find it uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Taylor Gibb at https://www.howtogeek.com/165268/how-to-add-open-powershell-here-to-the-context-menu-in-windows/ for the info.

You can edit your registry to add this option to standard right-click functions by running regedit (Win+R and type regedit) then under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`

From here you can add a new entry to your context menu.

1. Create a new key under shell, named "powershellmenu", change its (Default) value to "Open PowerShell here".
2. Create a new key under the newly created powershellmenu and name it "command"
3. Change the (Default) value of the command key to `C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'`

This should accomplish what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can edit the existing registry entry to make PowerShell part of the primary context menu rather than the extended context menu. The biggest hassle is that you don't have permission to edit the key by default and it is owned by *TrustedInstaller*. So you have to jump through the hoops of taking [ownership](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/how-to-take-ownership-of-registry-keys-and-assign-full-permissions/) and adding yourself with full control. Then you can edit these two registry keys:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Powershell
```

For both keys, delete the value named 'Extended':
[image]

After editing, it's a good idea to restore the permissions to their original state by first deleting the permissions entry you created for yourself and then restoring ownership to TrustedInstaller. The pricipal name is '**NT SERVICE\TrustedINstaller**'

Keith